# Deriving a formula from a set of points

Tags: polynomials

I have a set of values that are increasing non uniformly. I can figure out an equation for a constant increase, but this is not linear. How do I determine a formula for these points?

2179, 2197, 2247, 2337, 2485, 2741, 3140, 3730, 4681, 6100

Method for derivation and answer would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not quadratic either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple formula, as the data can be many things.  The usual first step is to plot it and see what it looks like. Most spreadsheets can give you a polynomial or exponential fit.  By eye, a cubic looks pretty good.

[image]

Comment: Okay I was worried there was no formula, thanks for the tip!

Comment: This formula is not exact.  It is the best fit cubic through them.  You can evaluate it in a spreadsheet to see how large the errors are.